# Disabling the hover behavior on winform buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a winform application using C# 4.0

I have a form with one button. I changed the button's BackColor to yellow. At runtime, the button's back color changes slightly when I move the mouse over it. I want to disable this. I want the color to remain the same no matter what happens.

Here's the form code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Something
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}



namespace Something
{
partial class Home
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Home));
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.button1, "button1");
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // Home
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(227)))), ((int)(((byte)(228)))));
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Home";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Home_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;



}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your form code? Perhaps there is a onMouseOver event handler attached to your button which changes the color?

Comment: It seems the better way is to handle both the MouseEnter and the MouseLeave events, isn't it?

Comment: That depends on how the button is changed. The button changes, so there has to be code that handles that. If that code is called upon MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, then those are the events that should not be raised. I'm not even sure there is a onMouseOver event (I don't think so) in WinForms, but you get the idea. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you already set `FlatStyle` to flat, it's simple that you can do something like this:

```
//place this code in your form constructor
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
button1.BackColorChanged += (s, e) => {
   button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you have already set **FlatStyle** to **Flat**. In **flatAppearance**, we can change **MouseOverBackColor** into **Transparent**.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

People like me don't know what a compiler is. I looked up what it was and found out how to do it. It should look something like this.

```
public Menu2**()
    {
        button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
        button1.BackColorChanged += (s, e) => {
            button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
        };
```

**Menu2 is the name of the form you're working on.

Comment: it does provide an answer to the question. It shows how to do it: an example.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you don't want to create your own button class the quick solution is to change the button's `FlatStyle` to `Flat`